# Python: More efficient way to get the intersection of two tuples?

Tags: python, split, tuples, intersection

I'm working on a project at the moment, for which I have to process >1 Billion lines.
This file consists of 4 tags that contains url's as follows:

```
<stackoverflow.com> <stackoverflow.org> <stackoverflow.net> <stackoverflow.biz>
```

I extract the lines from a txt file, after which I have to get the content of the 1 & 3 tags to feed them into another function

```
with open("file.txt", "r") as f:
    for i in f:
        tag1 = i.split("<")[:2][1][:-2]
        tag2 = i.split("<")[:5][3][:-2]
```

I feed these extracted tags into a function, I named it tupleFunction, that returns a number of tuples like:

from tag1:

```
('stackoverflow.com/123456','stackoverflow.com',stackoverflow.com') 
('stackoverflow.com/1234567','stackoverflow.com',stackoverflow.com') 
('stackoverflow.com/12345678','stackoverflow.com',stackoverflow.com')
```

from tag2:

```
('stackoverflow.com/654321','stackoverflow.com',stackoverflow.com') 
('stackoverflow.com/7654321','stackoverflow.com',stackoverflow.com') 
('stackoverflow.com/123456','stackoverflow.com',stackoverflow.com')
```

From the first element of the tuple, I need to get the intersection of both tuples which is in this case:

```
('stackoverflow.com/123456')
```

I reach this result and append it in a text file by running this code:

```
a = [f for f, *_ in tuple1]
b = [f for f, *_ in tuple2]
c = str(set(a).intersection(b))[2:-2]
with open("res.txt", "a") as output:
   output.write(c)
```

The code all together looks like:

```
with open("file.txt", "r") as f:
    for i in f:
        tag1 = i.split("<")[:2][1][:-2]
        tag2 = i.split("<")[:5][3][:-2]

        tuple1 = tupleFunction(tag1)
        tuple2 = tupleFunction(tag2)

        a = [f for f, *_ in tuple1]
        b = [f for f, *_ in tuple2]
        c = str(set(a).intersection(b))[2:-2]
        with open("res.txt", "a") as output:
             output.write(c)
```

My question is: Is there a more efficient way to perform the exact process? my current code needs a month to finish :-(

Help is highly appreciated!

Comment: Could you please provide a sample of the initial input? The one that contains the long URLs? Also, how are you running the last piece of code? In it part of a larger process?

Comment: How do you know that these particular lines are the cause of slowness? Did you use a profiler? For one, opening a file again and again for every single line you write to it is probably going to be _much_ slower than these few set and string manipulations.

Comment: @Roy2012 I edited the question, hope it's clearer now!

Comment: `c = str(set(a).intersection(b))[2:-2]` only 'works' for result sets with exactly one element.

Comment: The set intersection part looks fine; if anything, do not re-open the result file in each iteration of the loop. Also, no need to create lists if you then convert those to sets; just use a set comprehension `{... for ... in ...}` in the first place.

Comment: @Thomas  Thanks for the comment. How could I not re-open the file every time? The file is large >200GB, how can I load it once?

Comment: `with open("file.txt", "r") as f, open("res.txt", "a") as output:` should work; if not, just put the second `with` directly after the first `with` (also, this way might change `a` to `w`)

Comment: The first thing to do when there's a performance issue is to understand what's taking time. I would start by profiling the code - or even just measuring multiple iterations of specific sections.

Comment: BTW, isn't `tag1 = i.split("<")[:2][1]` the same as just `tag1 = i.split("<")[1]`? You basically say "take the first two elements, and then the second of those", which of course is just the second. Same for `tag2`, any maybe `split` only once.

Comment: @tobias_k thanks mate, your tips have been pretty useful!

Answer (score 0):

The files look like a CSV with custom delimiter and quotes. I'd probably load them in a `pandas` table and process it from there.